# Is there a way to bind a key to properly leave command mode?

Tags: key-bindings, ex-mode

(I put the tl;dr bit at the top)

**How can i bind <kbd>F10</kbd> for Vim so that when I hit <kbd>F10</kbd> while inside command (Ex) mode that the command in the command buffer is not actually executed?**

I have already tried the one thing that I know to do for the situation which is

```
cnoremap <F10> <ESC>
```

Background information follows...

I have a binding which for historical (arbitrary) reasons I have been using the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to conditionally control my unix systems. So basically what I needed to tell Vim to do is when I hit <kbd>F10</kbd> either have this function the same as the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (to exit insert mode for example) or do some other action if already in normal mode (such as move to next pane in `tmux`).

So that is the background that you didn't ask for about why I am binding <kbd>Esc</kbd> rather than mapping my <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at the OS level. It's a "smart" unintuitive crazy thing but it's intuitive for yours truly now :)

This has worked fantastically well through a small number of hundreds of thousands of lines of code over many years since I started doing this but one quirk remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>esc</kbd> in command line mode traditionally meant the same as <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That means, it executes your entered command and Vim behaves still the same, when  is mapped to another key. Several years ago, I even made a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/C3wh_Z_VXEo/4XUARHm5EA0J), to fix this, but it seems nobody cared too much about it.

Back to your question, simply map <kbd>F10</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> should do what you want, e.g. abort the entered command:

```
:cnoremap <f10> <c-c>
```

Comment: Oh wow I cannot believe I forgot to test what Esc does! Thanks! I used ctrl+c a lot in the past but it never occurred to me to try this.

Comment: As I fix this I find no less than 4 other examples in my vimrc of cnoremap's to <c-c>. This means that I knew about this aspect of Vim in the past. I knew it well. And then I completely forgot about it. Face, meet palm